# system.web.services.dll in Metro Application

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I want to use in my Metro application, a dll that usea system.web.services.dll. When I add it as a reference and compile, it fails for me with error `can't resolve assembly or windows metadata file system.web.services.dll`

If have a library written in C#, can I convert it to a .net core library?

Comment: Why do you want to use System.Web.Services? That's part of the legacy ASMX technology, which should not be used for new development.

Comment: Maybe time to not use old DLLs with new technologies?